# Efficiency of constraint strengthening in SMT solvers

Tags: z3, smt

One way to solve optimisation problems is to use an SMT solver to ask whether a (bad) solution exists, then to progressively add tighter cost constraints until the proposition is no longer satisfiable.  This approach is discussed in, for example, http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~oliveras/espai/papers/sat06.pdf and http://isi.uni-bremen.de/agra/doc/konf/08_isvlsi_optprob.pdf.

Is this approach *efficient*, though?  i.e. will the solver re-use information from previous solutions when attempting to solve with additional constraints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solver can reuse lemmas learned when trying to solve previous queries. Just keep in mind than in Z3 whenever you execute a `pop` all lemmas (created since the corresponding `push`)  are forgotten. So, to accomplish that you must avoid `push` and `pop` commands and use "assumptions" if you need to retract assertions. In the following question, I describe how to use "assumptions" in Z3:
[Soft/Hard constraints in Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439556/soft-hard-constraints-in-z3)

Regarding efficiency, this approach is not the most efficient one for every problem domain. On the other hand, it can be implemented on top of most SMT solvers. Moreover, Pseudo-Boolean solvers (solver for 0-1 integer problems) successfully use a similar approach for solving optimization problems.

Comment: Is there a way to save the lemmas from Z3 and add the lemmas to Z3 for solving later?