# Scala^Z3: Delete previous assertion

Tags: scala, z3

I want to use Scala^Z3 for incremental solving. In each iteration I want to

a) add some part of the formula

b) add an assertion

The formula should be preserved for every following iteration, but I would need to delete the assertion, if I cant fulfill it, because the assertion in the next iteration will be different.

So is there a way to delete previous statements? Z3Context.pop() sounds a little like what I need, but I could not find a description of what it does..

Would be very thankful for some help there!

Best wishes,
1428162

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, `ctx.pop()` is what you want. It can also take an argument, as in `ctx.pop(2)`, but it defaults to 1 if you omit it. Intuitively, puts the state of the solver back to where it was "`n` pushes ago".

So if you do:

```
ctx.assertCnstr(formula1)
ctx.push()

ctx.assertCnstr(extraAssertion)
ctx.check() match {
  case Some(true)  => ... // SAT
  case Some(false) => ... // UNSAT
  case None        => ... // UNKNOWN
}

ctx.pop(1)
```

...the state of the solver is reverted to what it was before you called `push()`.

Note that these behave exactly as their equivalent from the [Z3 C API](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi.html), so the documentation from there applies as well.

Note as well that calling `push` and `pop` on a context is deprecated as of Z3 4.0. The recommended way is now to have the context first create a solver, and then use `push` and `pop` on the solver directly (there was no notion of solver prior to Z3 4.0). Scala^Z3 hasn't caught up yet but you can expect that the change will eventually be propagated.

Comment: Thx for the answer + the additional infos! Guess I have to stick to push and pop for now.. But now that you told me how to use them, I would not want to change that anyway :)

Comment: Of course if you want to hack on Scala^Z3 and create a pull request on GitHub we'll be very grateful :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're right, you want to `pop` (remove) the last assertion.  To do this, you first need to save the current set of assertions with `push`.  This is how Z3 supports scope.

By add some part of the formula, I'm going to assume you mean to define a variable containing an additional chunk of some original large formula you're doing the incremental checking on.  I'll also assume the original formula is a large conjunction of sub-formulas.  This new formula will remain defined between pushes and pops (assuming you keep a variable referencing it).

Here is a link to an example of roughly the following pseudo-code in z3py, except in the z3py script I also assume the formula and the constraint are actually the same thing, but maybe you want to create some different constraint based on that piece of the subformula: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/LIxW

I haven't used Scala^Z3, but roughly you want to do the following:

```
formula // list containing parts (sub-formulas) of original large formula
while (formulaPart = formula.removeFirst()) // remove first element of list
    Z3Context.push() // save current set of assertions

    assertion = makeConstraint( formulaPart ) // assertion based on sub-formula

    Z3Context.assertCnstr( assertion ) // add new assertion

    if !Z3Context.check() // check if assertions cannot be satisfied
        Z3Context.pop() // remove most recent assertion
```

Here is an example using pop/push from the .NET API: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/test__managed_8cs_source.html#l00637

You'd also be interested in this: [Soft/Hard constraints in Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439556/soft-hard-constraints-in-z3)

Comment: Thx a lot, that answer really helped me out! I did a push() between adding the assertion and the pop(), but now you showed me how to do it, its working! :)