# Tactic to use soft constraints/assumptions only after a time-out?

Tags: timeout, constraints, z3

Assume that I have a Z3 preamble that includes several function declarations and definitional axioms (with explicit patterns), e.g., my own sequence axioms:

```
(declare-sort $Seq)
(declare-fun $Seq.nil () $Seq)
(declare-fun $Seq.len ($Seq) Int)
(declare-fun $Seq.con (Int $Seq) $Seq)
(declare-fun $Seq.at ($Seq Int) Int)
(declare-fun $Seq.in ($Seq Int) Bool)
...
(assert (forall ((xs $Seq)) (! ... )
(assert (forall ((xs $Seq) (x Int)) (! ... )
...
```

After this preamble has been emitted a lot of assertions are pushed to Z3, interspersed with calls to `check-set` to see whether certain negated formulas can be shown `unsat` (FYI: my context is software verification using symbolic execution).
Most of these assertions are simple and don't refuting them doesn't require the sequence axioms. However, from a few simple tests I get the impression that their presence nevertheless slows Z3 down.

I thus guarded the definitional axioms by an implication with a dummy boolean constant as the left-hand side of the implication (as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8441801)), e.g.,

```
(declare-const $useSeq Bool)
(assert (=> ($useSeq (forall ((xs $Seq)) (! ... )
```

and changed every `check-sat` that needs to reason about sequences into one that assumes `$useSeq`, i.e.,

```
(check-sat $useSeq)
```

**Question:** Is there a tactic/way to make Z3 use certain assertions only after a time-out? E.g.,

```
(check-sat-using (or-else (try-for smt 500) (smt $useSeq)))
```

I could of course manually emit a time-bounded `check-sat` first, followed by a `check-sat useSeq $useSeq` if needed, but it would be nice if it could be done with some kind of tactics.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this cannot be done with the current set of tactics available in Z3.